# Firing callback after multiple ajax requests are complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

```
loadInfo: function(){
    var jsonCounter = 0,
    room = ['room1','room2','room3'],
    dates = [],
    prices = []

    $.each(booking.rooms, function(key, room_name) {
        $.getJSON('/get_info.php?room='+room_name, function(data) {
            dates[room_name] = data
            jsonCounter++
        })
        $.getJSON('/get_info.php?room='+room_name+'&prices', function(data) {
            prices[room_name] = data
            jsonCounter++
        })

    })

    function checkIfReady() {
        if (jsonCounter === rooms.length * 2) {
            clearInterval(timer)
            run_the_rest_of_the_app()
        }
    }

    var timer = setInterval(checkIfReady, 100)

}
```

(Modified a lot, as it's part of a class etc etc.)

At the moment this feels a bit hackish, as the timer usage seems rubbish. I would use $.when and $.done, but I don't know how many rooms there might be, so I don't know what to put into when.

How do I ensure that run_the_rest_of_the_app() only gets called once all of the AJAX requests come back?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- `var activeAJAX = 0;`
- Before making an AJAX call, `activeAJAX++;`
- After completing an AJAX call (in the callback): `if (--activeAJAX == 0) { allDone(); }`

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to use when/done

```
loadInfo: function(){
    var room = ['room1','room2','room3'],
    dates = [],
    prices = [],
    requests = [];

    $.each(booking.rooms, function(key, room_name) {
        var aRequest;

        aRequest = $.getJSON('/get_info.php?room='+room_name, function(data) {
            dates[room_name] = data;
        });
        requests.push(aRequest);

        aRequest = $.getJSON('/get_info.php?room='+room_name+'&prices', function(data) {
            prices[room_name] = data;
        });
        requests.push(aRequest);

    })

    $.when.apply($, requests).done(run_the_rest_of_the_app);
}
```

Comment: Weirdly this doesn't work in my testing. the done bit fires before the requests are done fairly often. Odd.

Comment: Hmm.. i am wondering if we are seeing a race condition between the individual `success` callbacks and the `done` callback of the group. Are the requests really not done ? or just their callback not called when the `done` callback is executed?

Comment: I also have one extra one before the $.each, so it may be that that one completes before the first $.getJSON is triggered? Weird. In the end I stayed with my rubbish timer version, as I wanted a status bar, and it made it easy to do!