# Node.js: Best way to perform multiple async operations, then do something else?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

In the following code I am trying to make multiple (around 10) HTTP requests and RSS parses in one go.

I am using the standard `forEach` construct on an array of URIs I need to access and parse the result of.

Code:

```
var articles;

feedsToFetch.forEach(function (feedUri)
{   
        feed(feedUri, function(err, feedArticles) 
        {
            if (err)
            {
                throw err;
            }
            else
            {
                articles = articles.concat(feedArticles);
            }
        });
 });

 // Code I want to run once all feedUris have been visited
```

I understand that when calling a function once I should be using a callback. However, the only way I can think of using a callback in this example would be to call a function which counts how many times it has been called and only continues when it has been called the same amount of times as `feedsToFetch.length` which seems hacky.

So my question is, **what is the best way to handle this type of situation in node.js**.

Preferably without any form of blocking! (I still want that blazing fast speed). Is it promises or something else?

Thanks,
Danny

Comment: Yes, promises are the simplest way to go. If you'd rather cook up your own solution using standard JS, [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075526/firing-callback-after-multiple-ajax-requests-are-complete/10075575#10075575) can be easily adapted.

Comment: please show the code for the `feed()` function.

Comment: @Amadan, maybe it's personal preference, but I don't think Promises are the "simplest" way to go. I've provided an answer to expand on this.

Comment: You've figured it out: use a counter and count the number of requests made and completed. It's basically what async and promises do internally. About a year before the async library was written I wrote this answer to solve this exact problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631774/coordinating-parallel-execution-in-node-js/4631909#4631909 . This is a more advanced implementation that allows you to launch batches of async operations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250746/process-chain-of-functions-without-ui-block/13252018#13252018

Comment: @naomik: I'd say personal preference - I don't see aarosil's answer much more complex than yours.

Comment: @DanTonyBrown does it matter to you what order the articles end up in?  The `serial` option by @naomik below is the only one that will preserve the order, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @sequoiamcdowell with promises that would be a standard for loop... promises are an actual abstraction on sequencing things - it's a lot more sound and complete than the 'async' module, most modern languages have them under different names and they've been widely adopted.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum "promises is widely adopted [[by everything except IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises)]". I like how you critique my answer for using a lib completely overlooking the fact I provided a roll-your-own solution as well. At the same time, you're basically saying "use something that's not supported in IE or get a polyfill (see: "lib")".

Comment: I stand corrected-- .map preserves order.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**HACK-FREE SOLUTION**

[*Promises to be included in next JavaScript version*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

The popular Promise libraries give you an `.all()` method for this exact use case (waiting for a bunch of async calls to complete, then doing something else).  It's the perfect match for your scenario

Bluebird also has `.map()`, which can take an array of values and use it to start a Promise chain.

Here is an example using Bluebird `.map()`:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var request = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request'));

function processAllFeeds(feedsToFetch) {    
    return Promise.map(feedsToFetch, function(feed){ 
        // I renamed your 'feed' fn to 'processFeed'
        return processFeed(feed) 
    })
    .then(function(articles){
        // 'articles' is now an array w/ results of all 'processFeed' calls
        // do something with all the results...
    })
    .catch(function(e){
        // feed server was down, etc
    })
}

function processFeed(feed) { 
    // use the promisified version of 'get'
    return request.getAsync(feed.url)... 
}
```

Notice also that you don't need to use closure here to accumulate the results.

The [Bluebird API Docs](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md) are really well written too, with lots of examples, so it makes it easier to pick up.

Once I learned Promise pattern, it made life so much easier.  I can't recommend it enough.

Also, here is [**a great article**](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-callback-hell-promises-generators/) about different approaches to dealing with async functions using promises, the `async` module, and others

Hope this helps!

Comment: @naomik I updated the answer to reflect hack-free status

Answer (score 10):

**No hacks necessary**

I would recommend using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module as it makes these kinds of things a lot easier.

`async` provides [async.eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback) as an async replacement for `arr.forEach` and allows you to pass a `done` callback function when it's complete. It will process each items in a series, just as `forEach` does. Also, it will conveniently bubble errors to your callback so that you don't have to have handler logic inside the loop. If you want/require **parallel** processing, you can use [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each).

There will be **no blocking** between the `async.eachSeries` call and the callback.

```
async.eachSeries(feedsToFetch, function(feedUri, done) {

  // call your async function
  feed(feedUri, function(err, feedArticles) {

    // if there's an error, "bubble" it to the callback
    if (err) return done(err);

    // your operation here;
    articles = articles.concat(feedArticles);

    // this task is done
    done();
  });
}, function(err) {

  // errors generated in the loop above will be accessible here
  if (err) throw err;

  // we're all done!
  console.log("all done!");
});
```

Alternatively, you could build an array of async operations and pass them to [async.series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback). Series will process your results in a **series** (not parallel) and call the callback when each function is complete. The only reason to use this over `async.eachSeries` would be if you preferred the familiar `arr.forEach` syntax.

```
// create an array of async tasks
var tasks = [];

feedsToFetch.forEach(function (feedUri) {

  // add each task to the task array
  tasks.push(function() {

    // your operations
    feed(feedUri, function(err, feedArticles) {
      if (err) throw err;
      articles = articles.concat(feedArticles);
    });
  });
});

// call async.series with the task array and callback
async.series(tasks, function() {
 console.log("done !");
});
```

---

**Or you can Roll Your Own™**

Perhaps you're feeling extra ambitious or maybe you don't want to rely upon the `async` dependency. Maybe you're just bored like I was. Anyway, I purposely copied the API of `async.eachSeries` to make it easy to understand how this works.

Once we remove the comments here, we have just **9 lines of code** that can be reused for *any* array we want to process asynchronously! It will not modify the original array, errors can be sent to "short circuit" the iteration, and a separate callback can be used. It will also work on empty arrays. Quite a bit of functionality for just 9 lines :)

```
// void asyncForEach(Array arr, Function iterator, Function callback)
//   * iterator(item, done) - done can be called with an err to shortcut to callback
//   * callback(done)       - done recieves error if an iterator sent one
function asyncForEach(arr, iterator, callback) {

  // create a cloned queue of arr
  var queue = arr.slice(0);

  // create a recursive iterator
  function next(err) {

    // if there's an error, bubble to callback
    if (err) return callback(err);

    // if the queue is empty, call the callback with no error
    if (queue.length === 0) return callback(null);

    // call the callback with our task
    // we pass `next` here so the task can let us know when to move on to the next task
    iterator(queue.shift(), next);
  }

  // start the loop;
  next();
}
```

Now let's create a sample async function to use with it. We'll fake the delay with a `setTimeout` of 500 ms here.

```
// void sampleAsync(String uri, Function done)
//   * done receives message string after 500 ms
function sampleAsync(uri, done) {

  // fake delay of 500 ms
  setTimeout(function() {

    // our operation
    // <= "foo"
    // => "async foo !"
    var message = ["async", uri, "!"].join(" ");

    // call done with our result
    done(message);
  }, 500);
}
```

Ok, let's see how they work !

```
tasks = ["cat", "hat", "wat"];

asyncForEach(tasks, function(uri, done) {
  sampleAsync(uri, function(message) {
    console.log(message);
    done();
  });
}, function() {
  console.log("done");
});
```

Output (500 ms delay before each output)

```
async cat !
async hat !
async wat !
done
```

Comment: note is node/v8 vNext, it will have yield.  Search for that.

Comment: the asyncEach here behaves more like `async.eachSeries` than `async.each` fwiw.  `async.each` will fire off the http requests (or whatever) as fast as it can, i.e. concurrently; `asynSeries` (or the "serial" solution here) will do one after the next.  Unless I'm Mistaken.

Comment: @sequoiamcdowell, good catch. I've renamed the custom `asyncEach` to `asyncForEach` to imply that it does serial processing like `arr.forEach`. I've also updated the `async.each` to `async.eachSeries`. Thanks !

Comment: "No hacks necessary... Use this library" - I don't follow that logic, on the other hand NodeJS ships with promises which would make this trivial.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, Using a lib doesn't mean "hack". I also provided a "roll your own" solution.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I did not know node shipped with promises & my brand new install doesn't seem to have them.  What's the universal, no-hack way to access native promises in node.js today?

Comment: @sequoiamcdowell `$ echo "Promise" | node` should give you `ReferenceError: Promise is not defined`. This is a feature. Just add `bluebird` and all of your problems go away.

Comment: @sequoiamcdowell what version of Node are you using? It's in since about 0.11.13

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum So when you say node "ships with" Promises you mean "if you use the [very latest](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7ca5af87a0662a1f8dca2391ae90a6342592302b/ChangeLog) **unstable** release, and make sure to run it with the `--harmony` switch to enable experimental features, [node ships with promises]"?  This is a very peculiar definition of "no hacks" and of "ships with" :)  Incidentally it's funny you should say "since about" since the release you've named is *the very latest* tagged unstable release.

Answer (score 1):

using a copy of the list of url as a queue to keep track of arrivals makes it simple:
 (all changes commented)

```
var q=feedsToFetch.slice(); // dupe to censor upon url arrival (to track progress)

feedsToFetch.forEach(function (feedUri)
{   
        feed(feedUri, function(err, feedArticles) 
        {
            if (err)
            {
                throw err;
            }
            else
            {
                articles = articles.concat(feedArticles);
            }
            q.splice(q.indexOf(feedUri),1); //remove this url from list
            if(!q.length) done(); // if all urls have been removed, fire needy code
        });
 });

function done(){
  // Code I want to run once all feedUris have been visited

}
```

in the end, this is not that much "dirtier" than promises, and provides you chance to reload un-finished urls (a counter alone wont tell you which one(s) failed). for this simple parallel download task, it's actually going to add more code to your project implement Promises than a simple queue, and Promise.all() is not in the most intuitive place to stumble across. Once you get into sub-sub-queries, or want better error handling than a trainwreck, i strongly recommend using Promises, but you don't need a rocket launcher to kill a squirrel...