# Control flow code through an event in javascript

Tags: javascript, control-flow

```
[1,2,3].map(function(num) {
  client.fooBar(num);
  // don't move on until `foo` is emitted to `client`
});

client.on('foo', function(num) {
   console.log(num)
});
```

When `client.fooBar` is called, an asynchronous call is made and an event `foo` is emitted on `client`. If I only wanted to process one number at a time (don't move to `2` until `1` has been processed) what would the best way be to organize my code? This is node.js.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js: Best way to perform multiple async operations, then do something else?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268651/node-js-best-way-to-perform-multiple-async-operations-then-do-something-else)

Comment: is your client.on implemented in client side? or that is a callback that tells u that it has sent to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No. That's an entirely different question (switz).

No, it's not entirely different at all. You have a series that needs an asynchronous (event-driven) control structure around it.

Because your `fooBar` function fires a `foo` event rather than taking a callback, you need to attach a `foo` event listener to the control code to notify the loop when to proceed to the next element in the array.

Unless there's some other way of letting the control structure know when to proceed, I don't see another way of accomplishing your task.

This uses [async.eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback) to accomplish your goal

```
async.eachSeries([1,2,3], function(num, done) {
  client.once("foo", function() { done(); });
  client.fooBar(num);
}, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("all done!");
});
```

---

If you don't want to depend on the `async` lib, you can write your own `asyncForEach` function

```
function asyncForEach(arr, iterator, callback) {
  var queue = arr.slice(0);
  function next(err) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    if (queue.length === 0) return callback(null);
    iterator(queue.shift(), next);
  }
  next();
}
```

Then use it in your code

```
asyncForEach([1,2,3], function(num, done) {
  client.once("foo", function() { done(); });
  client.fooBar(num);
}, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("all done!");
});
```